# How do I use debounce in Input onChange events in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is where I use Debounce

```
const handleSearch = debounce((value: string) => {
    const filter = tableDataCopy.filter(
      (item) => item[condition].toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1,
    );
    setTableData(filter);
  }, 500);
```

onChange Event:

```
onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => handleSearch(e.target.value)}
```

debounce function:

```
export function debounce(func: Function, delay: number) {
  let timer: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;
  return function (this: any) {
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.call(this, ...arguments);
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

I got a parameter error in typescript :

```
TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
```

I know this is wrong but I don't know how to pass the argument in Debounce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `this` is a special function argument. It specifies the required type of the context (`this`) in a function. It doesn't count as a real argument. This means that `function (this: any) {}` is a function that takes zero arguments.

---

Second, *never* use the `arguments` keyword in typescript. It can be tricky, for a variety of reasons (it's not a real array, and it can't be typed to name a few). Instead accept a spread of arguments that get mapped to a variable.

Like:

```
function (...args: string[]) {}
```

---

Third, Typescript needs to know the function type to return from your debounce. `Function` isn't good enough. It needs to know the arguments your debounced function accepts. For this you have to use a generic type parameter.

This gets a bit more complicated.

```
function debounce<
  T extends unknown[]
>(
  func: (...args: T) => void,
  delay: number,
):
  (...args: T) => void
{
  let timer: number | null = null;
  return (...args: T) => {
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.call(null, ...args);
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

This is the generic parameter:

```
T extends unknown[]
```

And use it here as the `func` argument type:

```
func: (...args: T) => void
```

And in the return type of the function:

```
: (...args: T) => void
```

Now the function you pass to `debounce` will have its arguments noticed by the generic parameter, and the returned function will have the exact same arguments.

---

Lastly, you don't need to specify the event type in `onChange`. React knows the type of the element, so typescript can know the type of the arguments.

```
<input type="text" onChange={e => handleSearch(e.target.value)} />
```

---

[Working example on a TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&module=1&ssl=4&ssc=13&pln=4&pc=20&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTMBXAOw2AmrgBMkAjCGtJAHlLjgAqcJAA8YSakwDOcGgGtqEAO7UA2gF1SAPgAUfOFVoAuODoB0FlFADmUkwICUcALxa4ANwjAmAGn0sAGxQATxNqShBWJCg-ByN9c0sbO0EnVw8vJlIAb30ApHgYUGiwiKioOAAfOHCAgJcayjqAbn0iGEooRkSzK1t7NLdc-n5gTFMikGinNHyrAWKOGB1J6daRuFWK5zgpAoWppZ0dQbhhjYNOMzQUOp1agJ84C17kh3WRgF8nwJD3-U+rU+5DQDCk8AAFihJPkAMqoKBoCENFjsThIY7uW6UJAmcFQYDUaync78AD0ZJepG+cAArAAGen-CicIoMOAAMQgEBOZzaBU6jG4hLAlEKwTASGcACJxGJpXAGABhKFEqXZJAuNyqphwhFInRIMwwPoFMxYgI4hyfOBkrTUoA)

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves my problem. Have a nice day :)

Comment: This looks great. The only issue is that `setTimeout()` seems to return ` Timeout` instead of a `number`.